# How can I vote to close my own questions?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

On Stack Overflow, I read that users with a reputation of at least 250 can vote to close their own questions. Where is this option, and how do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be seeing a "close" link below your questions, between "edit" and "delete".

Unlike deleting your own questions - which happens immediately - a vote to close is just that. Four other users must also vote to close. Actually, that's not strictly true - a diamond moderator's vote is final.

Comment: Is that valid also when somebody else started the vote? I take that is not possible to vote for not closing the question, then.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - that's right. You can only vote to reopen once the question has been closed. Migrated questions stay migrated though.