# OP and Community are present in the list of users who marked the question as a duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

This [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289813/339911) was closed as an exact duplicate:

> [image: dup]

Why are both (OP and Community ♦ user) present in the list of voters for the
duplicate notice?

As far as I know if the OP decided to close their own question, only the Community ♦ user should present (not OP itself). [E.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289699/339911):

> [image: noOP]

There is no OP name (GhostCat) explicitly in the list.

Comment: Easy peasy. OP there has over 250 rep meaning they have reached privilege to [cast close vote on their own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54474/165773). That is when they [confirm duplicate at their question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/165773) their vote is displayed along with that of Community

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At [250 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) as well as being able to *view* open and close votes on your own questions you can also **cast** open and close votes. These have the same weight as votes from other users - i.e. 1 of 5 - so your name will appear along side all the other voters.

However, if you agree with the Community when they have cast close votes and flags that it treated as a binding close vote but it's assigned to Community.

What I'm guessing happened here is that the OP saw the close votes, agreed and cast their own (which may well not have been a duplicate vote). They then saw the Community raised message and clicked on that to complete the close process.

In your second example the user has less than 250 rep so would only have ever seen the Community generated message.

Comment: If your guessing is true, I think here is definitely a bug. Because voting 2 times for the same thing is too much.

Comment: @alexolut well the second time your not voting as such, just confirming the "Community" vote.

Comment: technically - yes. But I can't find any reason to vote for close own question as a dup without actual closing.

Comment: @alexolut maybe they didn't pick the duplicate option?