# Why not indicate the username of the OP when they click on "this solved my problem"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Why not indicate the username of the OP when they click on "this solved my problem"?

Instead, only "community"  is shown. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44911912/395857).

Comment: @Laurel Thanks. I'm not using this self-closing feature again.

Comment: [vote to close for another reason and you will be credited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289818/307988) :)

Comment: I like how this question about duplicates is a duplicate of a duplicated duplicate post.